# Making jDashboard Responsive

Tags: jquery, user-interface, responsive-design

jDashboard is an excellent Dashboard solution for developers looking to create a drag-and-drop UI for their users. However, it is greatly lacking in the responsive department.

How can jDashboard be made more responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Introduce some @media breakpoints into your CSS file as follows:

```
.jdash-column {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .jdash-column {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .jdash-column {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**Step 2.** Store the original widths of the rendered .jdash-columns as follows:

```
// Preserve original widths (TODO: Refactor to use .data())
var col_widths = new Object();
var uniq_col_id = 1;
$('.jdash-column').each(function() {
  var jdash_col_id = 'jdash_col-' + uniq_col_id;
  $(this).attr('id', jdash_col_id);
  col_widths[jdash_col_id] = $(this).css('width');
  uniq_col_id++;
});
```

**Step 3.** Finally, use a little jQuery to detect and respond to the window width to do two things: 1) set the width of .jdash-columns when below a certain breakpoint and 2) restore the original [stored] width of .jdash-columns when above a certain breakpoint. See below:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var window_width = $(window).width();

  if(window_width <= 767) {
    $('.jdash-column').each(function() {
      var jdash_col_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).css('width', '100%');
    });
  }

  if(window_width >= 768) {
    $('.jdash-column').each(function() {
      var jdash_col_id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).css('width', col_widths[jdash_col_id]);
    });
  }

});
```